# Cant generate locale float exception

Tags: locale

I am getting the error

```
 en_US.ISO-8859-1.../usr/sbin/locale-gen: line 177:  8091 Floating point exception(core dumped) localedef $no_archive -i $input -c -f $charset $locale_alias
```

when I run `sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8`

I am also getting :

```
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_COLLATE to default locale: No such file or directory
```

When I run locale -a

also  export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
returns
`-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)`

**Edit**:

This is from a copy of a virtual machine, I just copied in hyper v.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have an issue with the processor support on Hyper-V. You should try using Hyper-V CPU Compatibility Mode.

- Right click on the VM from Hyper-V and click on **Settings**.
- expand **Processor** and select **Compatibility**
- Then check the box for **Migrate to a physical computer with a different processor version**.

You may also try to check you initramfs is not configured for Virtualbox by generating a generic one:

- sudo nano /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf
- Check if **MODULES=most** instead of **MODULES=dep**
- Rebuild your initramfs with **sudo dpkg-reconfigure -plow initramfs-tools-core**

Finally reboot and retry to generate your locales.

Comment: So I want it to be dep or most? I have most

Comment: Nevermind, I read the comments in the file.

Comment: That didn't work

Comment: You have to keep most